# Camera Freeze (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I am try to make application that use camera. I divide to some class.

1. CameraSurface (extends SurfaceView)
2. ViewElement (extends view)
3. MainActivity (extends ViewElement)
4. SecondActivity (extends ViewElement)

Class that i declare as activity in manifest just MainActivity and SecondActivity. First when application run, it will execute MainActivity that will show CameraSurface, (there is instance of CameraSurface class in ViewElement, that add to ContentView in class ViewElement).
In MainActivity there is button that will move to MainActivity to SecondActivity. i use this code:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
      }
    }
    , 5000L);
```

SecondActivity same with MainActivity (Just have diffrent button, but still use camera), the problem is when application execute the SecondActivity camera become freeze. I still didn't know why this is happend. In CameraSurface class has part that use for release camera if camera instanse not equal to null. anybody know what happen with my application?

for additional information i get this on logcat:

> 01-14 16:38:23.899: D/memalloc(12581): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x506f0000 size:1843200 offset:1228800
>
> 01-14 16:38:23.899: D/memalloc(12581): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x509b2000 size:614400 offset:0
>
> 01-14 16:38:23.899: D/memalloc(12581): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x50ca4000 size:1228800 offset:614400
>
> 01-14 16:38:24.389: D/memalloc(12581): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x50dd0000 size:4829184 offset:4804608

Answer (score 0):

i can think of two reason :
1) You are invoking camera surface on both the activities, try to release camera before launching second activity.
2) since you are using SurfaceView for Camera, the operation is trying to run on OpenGL thread.
 try this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
    //make call to your second activity
    }
    }
```

Comment: i still didn't sure what i get from your answer. so, 1st i must release camera before launcing second activity. that means before this code `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
      }
    }
    , 5000L);`

and use the code from you to change my code to call secondActivity right?

Comment: i was not sure of the reasons for the camera to freeze. those two were the probable solution i gave (which may work for you).

and yes use runOnUIMThread with runnable to start your second activity inside run() method

Comment: i use both of your suggestion and try it on 2 device, 1st device i got same problem, camera freeze. 2nd device i got black background.

Comment: okay just for debugging sake, can you launch your second activity directly (make it as the main activity) to see if you second activity is successfully creating camera surface or not.

Comment: i set secondActivity to execute first when run application, an it success creating camera surface.